# Pass data from Form to multiple web pages using single JavaScript source file

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple login page with hardcoded username and password, I was successful in calling the next page once the login credentials are passed but I am having a tough time passing the user name entered in page 1 to appear on page 2.

I tried to find a way to make user inputs as global variables in js file so I can use the same variables in the second page but I am unsuccessful.

greeter.html

```
<body>
<h1>Simple Login Page</h1>
<form name="login">
    Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
    Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form);" value="Login"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
<p id = "passwarn"></p>
<script language="javascript" src="source.js">

</script>
</body>
```

source.js

```
function check(form) { /*function to check userid & password*/
/*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are 
matching*/
let uid = form.userid.value;
let pswrd = form.pswrd.value;
if(uid == "shiva" && pswrd == "mypswrd") {
    window.open('test.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password 
matches*/
}
else {
    document.getElementById("passwarn").innerHTML = "User name or 
password is incorrect!"/*displays error message*/
}
}
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script language="javascript" src="source.js"></script>
<h1> Hello <span id = "UI"></span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I want Hello shiva printed on the test.html page, I do not want to use jquery while doing so, is there any way?

Comment: Are you ok using cookies!

Comment: Yes sure, but I don't know how!

Comment: Note this is not secure at all and in order for a new page to know the entered credentials you would either need to store them (localStorage,cookies) or pass them in url get parameters (`http://..../?username=blah&...`). Making the variables global wont matter for newly opened pages as those pages are in a different environment.

Comment: I totally understand this is not secure, but I need to show the working of this requirement. that's all. It doesn't matter how!

Comment: Dont use .html extension use .php and use Ajax to post the data and then display the required content in new window using sessions

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reference the value from the opening page in test.html.

To make things more straightforward, add an ID to the Username field :

```
Username <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid">
```

Then you can grab and display the value from the opened window like this :

```
<h1> Hello 
  <script>   
     document.write(window.opener.document.getElementById("userid").value)  
  </script>
</h1>
```

If you want to do things a little more elegantly, you could keep the scripting in your .js file and change the innerHTML of your "UI" span from there.

Bear in mind that cross-origin scripting rules mean that this will only work when served from the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comments from your question two key points to identify

1. This is a very insecure way to do this
2. You may want to use cookies if the user if going to traverse many pages (not sponsoring, but I would recommend js-cookie, I have used it for a while and it's pretty robust)

In order to get what i believe you wanted to work i had to do a couple of this.

1. Put your JS on the page as for testing it quicker to have it all accessible on one page
2. I use function that is for parameter grabbing (yes this is completely insecure but would achieve what you want, a cookie would be more secure) you can find it [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/).
3. I renamed your inputs from names to ID's as they are more accessible in javascript this way.

This function when used with decode and encode URI components in javascript will help you pass the data from one page to another see code below

Greeter.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple Login Page</h1></script>
    <form name="login">
        Username<input type="text" id="userid"/>
        Password<input type="password" id="pswrd"/>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="LoginSubmit"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
    <p id = "passwarn"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./source.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then your test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Hello <span id="UI"></span></h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./source.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Finally your source.js

```
 window.onload = checkpage(window.location.href);
 
function checkpage(url){
    if(url.split('/').pop() == 'greeter.html'){
        document.getElementById('LoginSubmit').addEventListener('click',function () {
            var uid = document.getElementById('userid').value;
            var pswrd = document.getElementById('pswrd').value;
            console.log(uid, pswrd);
            check(uid, pswrd);
        });
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("UI").innerHTML = getAllUrlParams(decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)).uid;
    }
}
    
function check(uid, pswrd) { /*function to check userid & password*/
    /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are 
    matching*/
    let redirect = "test.html"
    let parameters = encodeURIComponent('uid='+uid);
    if(uid == "shiva" && pswrd == "mypswrd") {
        window.open(redirect+"?"+parameters)/*opens the target page while Id & password 
    matches*/
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("passwarn").innerHTML = "User name or password is incorrect!"/*displays error message*/
    }
}
    
function getAllUrlParams(url) {
// get query string from url (optional) or window
var queryString = url ? url.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.slice(1);
// we'll store the parameters here
var obj = {};
// if query string exists
if (queryString) {
    // stuff after # is not part of query string, so get rid of it
    queryString = queryString.split('#')[0];
    // split our query string into its component parts
    var arr = queryString.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // separate the keys and the values
        var a = arr[i].split('=');
        // set parameter name and value (use 'true' if empty)
        var paramName = a[0];
        var paramValue = typeof (a[1]) === 'undefined' ? true : a[1];
        // (optional) keep case consistent
        paramName = paramName.toLowerCase();
        if (typeof paramValue === 'string') paramValue = paramValue.toLowerCase();
        // if the paramName ends with square brackets, e.g. colors[] or colors[2]
        if (paramName.match(/\[(\d+)?\]$/)) {
            // create key if it doesn't exist
            var key = paramName.replace(/\[(\d+)?\]/, '');
            if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = [];
            // if it's an indexed array e.g. colors[2]
            if (paramName.match(/\[\d+\]$/)) {
                // get the index value and add the entry at the appropriate position
                var index = /\[(\d+)\]/.exec(paramName)[1];
                obj[key][index] = paramValue;
            } else {
                // otherwise add the value to the end of the array
                obj[key].push(paramValue);
            }
        } else {
            // we're dealing with a string
            if (!obj[paramName]) {
                // if it doesn't exist, create property
                obj[paramName] = paramValue;
            } else if (obj[paramName] && typeof obj[paramName] === 'string'){
                // if property does exist and it's a string, convert it to an array
                obj[paramName] = [obj[paramName]];
                obj[paramName].push(paramValue);
            } else {
                // otherwise add the property
                obj[paramName].push(paramValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

return obj;
}
```

So long as your HTML files are in the same folder you can run this. The main thing to notice is that you are binding the event listener to the element, getting the values input and then submitting them to the function.

I have added a function that retrieves the url of the page location and pops out the last bit of it and runs a check on it to ensure you are looking at the right place to run the correct code. as this runs on load then the subsequent functions run after. You can further refactor this to modularise it and ensure that it's cleaner to read if you wanted.

Splitting it out this way will make it easier when trying to implement a cookie as you can in the event listener (with a cookie created) can save those values to it on your greet page and then call them back after on your test page.

Hope that helps